# manipulate a 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2 Dimentional array in php as follow :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 50
        )

)
```

I want to manipulate it as follow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 67
            [2] => 67
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 50
        )

)
```

Means I want to take first elements of all inner arrays in one array and 2nd element in another array.

How can I manipulate this. Plz help

Comment: Try plain old `for` or `foreach` first, then show us your best attempt.

Comment: where is your PHP code?

Comment: I am not getting thats why I was asking ...

Comment: I am little newbie to this, so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general solution that works regardless of how many items you have in the array and the sub-arrays:

```
// Set up an array for testing
$my_array = array( array(10, null), array(67, null), array(67, 50));

/**
 * Our magic function; takes an array and produces a consolidated array like you requested
 * @param array $data The unprocessed data
 * @return array
 */
function consolidate_sub_arrays($data)
{
    /**
     * The return array
     * @var array $return_array
     */
    $return_array = array();
    // Loop over the existing array
    foreach ($data as $outer) {
        // Loop over the inner arrays (sub-arrays)
        foreach($outer as $key => $val) {
            // Set up a new sub-array in the return array, if it doesn't exist
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $return_array)) {
                $return_array[$key] = array();
            }
            // Add the value to the appropriate sub-array of the return array
            $return_array[$key][] = $val;
        }
    }
    // Done!
    return $return_array;
}

// Just to verify it works; delete this in production
print_r(consolidate_sub_arrays($my_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following script:

```
$array1 = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($array1[$i]); $j++) {
        $array2[$j][$i] = $array1[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be semicolons, not commas?

Comment: This is really inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can `array_map()` instead of loop. Example:

```
$newArr[] = array_map(function($v){return $v[0];},$arr);
$newArr[] = array_map(function($v){return $v[1];},$arr);
```

Or can use `array_column()` if your `PHP 5.5+`

```
$newArr[] = array_column($arr, 0);
$newArr[] = array_column($arr, 1);

print '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the initial array and create a new array in the format you want it.

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($input_array as $in ) {
    $new_array[0][] = $in[0];
    $new_array[1][] = $in[1];
}
print_r($new_array);
```